# C Program not Comparing chars correctly

Tags: c

I am working on this C code and I am confused why this is not working. I have looked at other questions here for comparing 2 chars and I have done it the exact same way but for some reason it isn't working.

What happens when it runs is that it will work for t and o, but not for c, even though I have implemented them all the same way.

Split_string was provided to us (no bugs) and returns the number of words in the string inputted via the keyboard. It also takes in an array of strings and puts each word at a different index.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
    char input[100];
    printf("What commmand would you like to use? t, o, or c\n");
    while(fgets(input, 100, stdin)!=NULL){
            char ** ptr  = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
            int wordno = split_string(input, ptr);


            if((*ptr[0]=='t') && wordno==1) {
                    text(root_ptr);
            } else if(*ptr[0]=='t' && wordno>1){
                    printf("No arguments for function t\n");
            } else if(*ptr[0]='o' && wordno==9){
                    open(root_ptr);
            } else if(*ptr[0]=='o' && wordno != 9){
                    printf("Need 8 attributes to open o\n");
            } else if(*ptr[0]=='c' && wordno==2){
                    open(root_ptr);
            } else if(*ptr[0]=='c' && wordno !=2){
                    printf("Only need 2 arguments to copy\n");
            } else {
                  printf("Please enter a value command\n");
            }
             printf("Enter t to text, o to open or c to copy\n");

    }
```

Comment: Please specify the circumstances of its failure for `c`, and what the output is that is wrong, and what the expected output is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the following line. There is a = missing, so you actually assign `o` to the first element of your array instead of comparing with `o`. Afterward, it can never be `c`.

```
} else if(*ptr[0]='o' && wordno==9){
```

Comment: And a standard addition to such an answer would be to *turn the compiler warnings on!*

Answer (score 2):

The error is here:

```
else if(*ptr[0]='o' && wordno==9){
```

where you force the first character to *be* 'o'. For that reason I usually write comparisons in the [Yoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) form:

```
if (('o' == (*ptr[0])) ...
```

even if it at first it looked awkward and is overkill. If an equal sign you forget, an error the compiler will throw.

However, this kind of behaviour should have been caught by activating the full warnings on the compiler. I strongly suggest you to keep them on at all times.

Also, you allocate the memory again at each cycle, causing a leak (this won't bite you very soon, if at all, but still):

```
char ** ptr  = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
```

Finally, you might be better served by a `switch` statement:

```
switch(*ptr[0]) {
    case 't':
        ...
        break;
    ...
    default:
        printf("Huh?\n");
        break;
}
```